# Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress - PromiseObjecs / For Loops

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
```

Essentially I am trying to run two promise objects simultaneously within a for loop:

```
angular.module('core').controller('HomeController', function($q, $http, $scope) {

for (var i = 0; i < window.config.Environments.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j < window.config.Clusters[i] + 1; j++) {

//Promise Object 1
        promiseObj.physical[window.config.Environments[i] + "#Cluster" + j] = $http.get('url/search?idc=' + window.config.Environments[i] + '&type=Physical&cluster=' + j).success(function(i,j) {
            return function(data) {

            $scope.servers = data; // get data from json

            angular.forEach($scope.servers, function(item) {

                //some code
            });
            }

        }(i,j));
    //Promise Object 1
           promiseObj.virtual[window.config.Environments[i] + "#Cluster" + j] = $http.get('url/search?idc=' + window.config.Environments[i] + '&type=Virtual&cluster=' + j).success(function(i,j) {
            return function(data) {

            angular.forEach($scope.virtualservers, function(item) {
  //some code


            });

            }

        }(i,j));

}
}
});
```

- Why does this error occur (apologies for my ignorance but I don't understand where I am calling $digest)

Thank you in advance

Comment: You would get that error if you were calling `$scope.$apply()` when a digest cycle was already running. So you were calling `$apply()` in Angular space so to speak, instead of a 3rd party callback out of scope for example. In the code you've omitted are you calling `$scope.$apply()`?

Comment: no, you see all of the angular code. The rest of the code is simply summing some variables together - removing this code does not solve the error

Comment: @ste2425 - Any advice?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I personally have not been in this situation. What i would do to trouble shoot would be removing one of the AJAX calls, see if there's conflicts there. The other thing would be more structural. I've tried not to be in that situation. Instead of many AJAX calls with little bits of data i perform one AJAX call passing all the data and let the server deal with it. On a side note it's good practice for `$scope` to be used as your first param. Shouldn't make much difference though as Angular works it out by name. Are you hoping to store to result of the success CB in the promiseObj?